# Big endian and Little endian representations

Tags: assembly, endianness

If I write the following

```
section .data
    align 4
    X:  db 1
    Y:  dw 5
    Z:  db 0x11
section .text
    add dword [X], 0xAA000101
```

I'm trying to understand the differences between the big endian and the little endian representations, and I don't understand what will be the value of each variable for each representation? Will they be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at these pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the list of endiannesses for all architectures/instruction sets

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a big-endian configuration, the most significant byte of a doubleword (32-bits on x86) is stored in the smallest address, and the least significant byte is stored in the largest address.
In a little-endian configuration, the least significant byte is stored in the smallest address.

Let's take the big-endian example first:

If we lay out your variables in memory in a big-endian configuration we get:

```
; -> Address increases ->

X: 01
Y: 00 05
Z: 11
```

or, grouped together:

```
 01 00 05 11
MSB       LSB
```

When viewed as a 32-bit value that equals `0x01000511`. Adding `0x01000511` and `0xAA000101` gives us `0xAB000612`. If we view the individual bytes in memory again we get:

```
; -> Address increases ->
AB 00 06 12
```

So the result is:

```
X = 0xAB
Y = 6
Z = 0x12
```

---

In a little-endian configuration we would have:

```
; -> Address increases ->

X: 01
Y: 05 00
Z: 11
```

or, grouped together:

```
 01 05 00 11
LSB       MSB
```

Viewed as a 32-bit value that equals `0x11000501`. Adding `0xAA000101` gives us `0xBB000602`. And when we view the individual bytes we get:

```
02 06 00 BB
```

With the result:

```
X = 2
Y = 6
Z = 0xBB
```

(Note: all x86 processors, AFAIK, are little-endian)