# How to read objdump in C

Tags: c

Code

```
#define     TEXT_LEN    256
#define     NUM_NUMBERS (2*65536)

    int     numNumbers = NUM_NUMBERS;
```

PuTTY command for global variable **numNumbers**

```
objdump -s -j .data assign1-0
```

Output of command

```
602070 00000000 00000200
```

Hello,
Can someone help me understand this output or if I put the wrong command?
Im trying to find global variable **numNumbers** using **objdump**.
But im pretty sure the output should be 00020000 because numNumbers is 131072 (2*65536) but it's coming out 00000200 which is 512 from hexadecimal to decimal.
Am I reading it wrong and the output is correct or is the command wrong to find a global variable?

Comment: You are probably on a [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) computer, and so the bytes that make up your int are not in the order in which you're used reading digits or bits as a human. Familiarize yourself with the concept of endianness.

Comment: You are probably working with a Little Endian architecture. How about this explanation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/24348873/14215102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably on a [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) computer, and so the bytes that make up your int are not in the order in which you're used reading digits or bits as a human. Familiarize yourself with the concept of endianness.

Comment: Thanks! It makes more sense with that.